# Solidity class inherit an interface but doesn't implement all its function

Tags: solidity, interfaces

I have an interface IA and a contract A which inherit IA. Now if there's a function a() in IA, but I don't implement a() in A. Is there a default behavior when calling A.a()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your smart contract will not compile if it does not implement all of the functions in the interface IA, unless it is an abstract contract and cannot be deployed directly.

And another smart contract that will derive from it will have to implement the functions missing in your smart contract A.

read more [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-all-about-interfaces-f547d2869499)